# Rerun external scripts for new DOM elements added by .load

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, load

For example I have several third-party external scripts which adds a lightbox for my images and some styling stuff for them too.

But when I load new `img` elements via `.load(site.com #divcontainer)` function, my third-party external scripts ignores them.

How can I fix this? I need to rerun this script for new DOM elements.

Comment: If plugin doesn't support any delegation method, ya, you need to rerun it on new added elements

Comment: I thought reruning same scripts on the same page can cause some conflicts